# Thin metal piece from 2003 Ford Windstar

Tags: part-identification, windstar

I found a thin piece of metal under the front of my 2003 Ford Windstar van.  It is somewhat circular and has three holes for bolts.  It doesn't appear to be damaged.  Any ideas about where this came from?

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking it doesn't belong to your Windstar, but I don't know for sure. I think you'd have to lose a lot more than what you have there to have lost this off of your vehicle. That's my gut check, because I don't know for sure.

Comment: Are there any markings in it?

Comment: Thanks, there are no markings.  It's a mystery.  I'll just conclude it got dragged into the garage somehow.